# Ошибка при открытии файла

Tags: delphi, excel, ole

Здравствуйте! Вижу вопрос уже канул в лету, а проблема то осталась. Немного переформулирую.

Возникла небольшая проблема и я никак не могу понять, в чём тут может быть дело. Есть код:

```
...
 odOpenF.FileName:='';
 if odOpenF.Execute then
  begin
   try
    //При выполнении следующего оператора возникает исключительная ситуация
    EXL:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
    EXL.Visible:=false;
    EXL.Workbooks.Open(odOpenF.FileName);
    ...
```

Причём возникает только в том случае, если я в появляющемся dialog открытия файла, дважды щёлкаю по выбираемому файлу, а не выбираю, а затем нажимаю "Открыть" (в этом случае всё проходит нормально).

Без `try.. except.. end` возникают следующие ошибки:

[image]

А иногда:

[image]

Ещё пару раз выдавал что-то там "недостаточно ресурсов", но я тогда не отскриншотил, а сообщение больше не появлялось.

Причём видимых причин для всего этого нет.

Ещё проводил один любопытный тест, в коде (на том месте где комментарий) писал `MessageDlg(odOpenF.FileName, mtInformation, [mbOk], 0)` (ну мало ли, а вдруг как-то полевому заполняется `FileName`). После этого ошибка снова переставала возникать.

В общем резюмируя скажу: что-то глючит. Однозначно где-то я ступил в коде, где именно - без понятия. Может быть вы подскажите?

**Дополнение.** Сегодня тестил на других компьютерах - ошибок не было. Похоже программа глючит только с ОСью х64

Comment: Сори за то, что слишком часто поднимаю тему в топ. Исправляю обшипки и очепятки

Comment: По существу - не знаю, но вот этот код выглядит полной бессмыслицей

    odOpenF.FileName:='';
    odOpenF.Execute();
    ... 
    if odOpenF.FileName<>'' then

поправьте заодно в `if odOpenF.Execute then ...`

Comment: Поправил, оставил только

    odOpenF.FileName:='';

чтобы при открытии диалога `odOpenF` в нем не отоброжался путь к последнему открываемому файлу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл в чём ошибка. В случае записи в файл excel, вместо этого кода:

```
EXL:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
EXL.Visible:=false;
EXL.Workbooks.Open(odOpenF.FileName);
```

Лучше использовать этот:

```
EXL:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
EXL.Workbooks.Open(odOpenF.FileName);
EXL.ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets[1].EnableSelection := $FFFFEFD2;
EXL.ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets[1].Protect('123', False, True, True, True);
```

По окончании работы с файлом, тогда ещё можно UnProtect поюзать (если очень надо)

Если объяснять на пальцах - так мы протектим наш excel от одновременного доступа и всего подобного.